# Laravel file upload name must be unique

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

As the title says I need for when user uploads a file for name to be unique, and if not throw a error.

This is my code

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'file' => 'unique:files,name',
]);
```

But it still passes and insert data into database. Does anyone have idea?

EDIT:

Here is html form

```
    {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/upload', 'files' => true)) !!}
    {!! Form::text('description','document description') !!}
    {!! Form::select('users', $users,null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a user'])  !!}
    {!! Form::text('commentary','commentary') !!}
    {!! Form::select('cat',$categories, null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a category'] ) !!}
    {!! Form::file('file') !!}
    {!! Form::token() !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Upload') !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And this is controller

```
if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $upload->title = Auth::User()->id;
        $object = $request->users;
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $file->move(public_path(). '/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $upload->name = $file->getClientOriginalName(),
        $upload->size = $file->getClientsize();
        $upload->description = $request->description;
        $upload->cat = $request->cat;
        $upload->commentary = $request->commentary;
        $upload->type = $file->getClientMimeType();
        $upload->save();
    }
```

Yes the table name is 'files' and column name is 'name'

Comment: the best solution for this is, Upload file in any temp_folder and then move the file in the main folder with the new name and add a name with the timestamp so it will be unique

Comment: So the table is `files` and the column you are verifying to be unique is `name`?

Comment: yes, in the name column I insert $file->getClientOriginalName();

Comment: column name is `name` right?

Comment: what is your table name?

Comment: Can you post the html input?

Comment: here I posted addition. Yes column name is 'name' and table name is 'files'

Comment: You can check before uploading file if in storage file with specific name exists by doing `Storage::disk('public')->has('file.ext')`. By the way are you taking care of file extension?

Comment: didn't cross my mind, is there a way to remove it(I know the php way, I'm talking about "laravel" way)

Comment: I like to use `while` loops for that. You can do `while` the file exists (using `storage::has()`) append an increasing number (such as `$i++`) to the original file name.